# Visual Studio 2019 (Professional) is compatible with BizTalk Server 2016?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper

Could anyone please confirm if Visual Studio 2019 (Professional) is compatible with BizTalk Server 2016?

Earlier we were using Visual studio 2015 and Biztalk 2016 Server (earlier works fine). But now we are planning to use Visual studio 2019 ( .Net4.8) with Biztalk 2016 Server.

Please confirm about compatibility, as we are having multiple .btproj files in our solutions.

my expectation is to build the project successfully, but i am not able to build it complete on VS 2019, but build able in VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

For BizTalk 2016 you need Visual Studio 2015, as per [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2016)

For each version of BizTalk there has always been a specific version of Visual Studio required.

You can only use Visual Studio 2019 for developing BizTalk 2020 solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Could you please suggest some official links for confirmation  "For each version of Biz Talk there has always been a specific version of Visual Studio required."

Comment: with Biztalk server 2016 i could only use VS 2015 ?

Comment: @Tech_dopamine I've been working with BizTalk since BizTalk 2004.  If you search for Software and Hardware requirements for BizTalk VERSION, you will find the page for that version.  Or you can find them linked from my blog article  BizTalk supported Microsoft .Net Frameworks & August 2019 Windows Updates https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/biztalk-supported-microsoft-net-frameworks-august-2019-windows-updates-msbts/